# Firebase "Operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xcmA.png)

i got an error when i tried to use firebase "sendSignInLinkToEmail". i was succesfully send the link to the email, but when i clicked on the link, i got this error. but if i copy the api key in the url then paste to target url, it work normally, i can continue the registratio. any idea how to fix it? the code looks like this

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const action = {
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_REGISTER_COMPLETE,
        handleCodeInApp: true,
    };

    await auth
        .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, action)
        .then(function () {
            toast.success(`✔ Success!. A link has been sent to ${email}`, {
                position: 'top-center',
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
            });
            window.localStorage.setItem('emailForRegister', email);
            setEmail('');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message)
        });
};
```